# Context Provider not working in Next with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context

The error is "Property 'Provider' does not exist on type 'ReactElement<SelectContext, string | JSXElementConstructor>'"

```
const RoomsCards = ({ rooms }: IRooms) => {
      interface SelectContext {
        selected: number
        setSelected: (e: any) => void
      }
      const SelectedContext = React.createElement<SelectContext>('selected')
      const [currentSelected, setCurrentSelected] = useState<number>()
      return (
        <SelectedContext.Provider value={{ currentSelected, setCurrentSelected }}>
          {React.Children.toArray(
            rooms.map((CurrentRoom: IRoomDetail) => MainCard(CurrentRoom))
          )}
        </SelectedContext.Provider>
      )
    }
    
    export default RoomsCards
```

i am using:
"react": "^17.0.2",
"next": "^12.1.5",
"typescript": "4.5.2",
"@types/react": "17.0.37",

Answer (score 2):

```
const SelectedContext = React.createElement<SelectContext>('selected')
```

Creating a context is done using `createContext`, not `createElement`. Additionally, you need to do this outside of RoomsCards, so you're not creating a brand new context on every render. And finally, your default value `"selected"` doesn't match the type you specified, so you'll need to change that to satisfy typescript.

```
interface SelectContext {
  selected: number;
  setSelected: (e: any) => void;
}
const SelectedContext = React.createContext<SelectContext>({
  selected: 0
  setSelected: () => {}
});

const RoomsCards = ({ rooms }: IRooms) => {
  const [currentSelected, setCurrentSelected] = useState<number>();
  return (
    <SelectedContext.Provider value={{ currentSelected, setCurrentSelected }}>
      {React.Children.toArray(
        rooms.map((CurrentRoom: IRoomDetail) => MainCard(CurrentRoom))
      )}
    </SelectedContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default RoomsCards;
```